# How to add autoscale to graph with tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello good people of the Internet. So there is a graph and a problem with that. When it create line, the line draws out of boundries, i need it to auto enlarge axes and/or auto scale already drawn lines.

```
import tkinter
import math
def plot_x_axe(x0, y0, x1):
    x_axe=[]
    xx=(x0, y0)
    x_axe.append(xx)
    xx=(x1, y0)
    x_axe.append(xx)
    canvas.create_line(x_axe, fill="black", width=2)

def plot_y_axe(x0, y0, y1):
    y_axe=[]
    yy=(x0, y1)
    y_axe.append(yy)
    yy=(x0, y0)
    y_axe.append(yy)
    canvas.create_line(y_axe, fill="black", width=2)

def DrawGraph():
    #getting variables to def
    dta=sc.get()
    dta2=sp.get()
    alpha=dta*math.pi/180
    dtlbl=clist.get()
    # cleaning canvas for text
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1i, y1i, x1i, y1i, fill="#eeeeff")
    
    g=9.8
    v0=dta2
    #
    S=int((v0**2)*math.sin(2*alpha)/g)
    H=int(((v0**2)*(math.sin(alpha))**2)/(2*g))
    #
    points=[]
    for x in range(x0i, x1i):
        xx=(x-x0)
        y=(xx*math.tan(alpha))-((xx**2)*g/(2*(v0**2)*(math.cos(alpha)**2)))
        if y > 0 :
            yy=int(y0-y)
        else:
            yy=y0i
        pp=(x, yy)
        points.append(pp)
# creating lines
    canvas.create_line(points, fill=dtlbl, smooth=1)
# graph's variables
    dtext="range: "+str(S)
    vtext="Height: "+str(H)
    canvas.create_text(x1i-70, y1i-30, text=dtext,
        fill=dtlbl, anchor="w")
    canvas.create_text(x1i-70, y1i-10, text=vtext,
        fill=dtlbl, anchor="w")
#

# main part
tk=tkinter.Tk()
tk.title("flight simulation")
# top frame with buttons and list
menuframe=tkinter.Frame(tk)
menuframe.pack({"side":"top", "fill":"x"})
# title for list
lbl=tkinter.Label(menuframe)
lbl["text"]="choose your color:"
lbl.pack({"side":"left"})
# int list
clist=tkinter.StringVar(tk)
clist.set('black')
cspis=tkinter.OptionMenu(menuframe, clist,
    'red',
    'green',
    'blue',
    'cyan',
    'magenta',
    'purple',
    'black')
cspis.pack({"side":"left"})
# button for def DrawGraph
btnOk=tkinter.Button(menuframe)
btnOk["text"]="DRAW IT"
btnOk["command"]=DrawGraph
btnOk.pack({"side":"left"})
# button to exit
button=tkinter.Button(menuframe,text="Close")
button["command"]=tk.quit
button.pack({"side":"right"})
# title for angle
lbl2=tkinter.Label(tk)
lbl2["text"]="angle, degrees:"
lbl2.pack({"side":"top"})
# angle slider
sc=tkinter.Scale(tk, from_=0, to=90, orient="horizontal")
sc.pack({"side":"top", "fill":"x"})
#
# starting speed
lbl3=tkinter.Label(tk)
lbl3["text"]="starting speed in metters per second"
lbl3.pack({"side":"top","fill":"x"})
# speed slider
sp=tkinter.Scale(tk, from_=1, to=150, orient="horizontal")
sp.pack({"side":"top", "fill":"x"})
# canvas
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(tk)
canvas["height"]=1080
canvas["width"]=1920
canvas["background"]="#eeeeff"
canvas["borderwidth"]=2
canvas.pack({"side":"bottom"})
#
line_ids= []
# axes of coordinates

x0=50.0
x1=450.0
y0=800.0
y1=50.0
#
x0i=int(x0)
x1i=int(x1)
y0i=int(y0)
y1i=int(y1)

plot_x_axe(x0i, y0i, x1i)
plot_y_axe(x0i, y0i, y1i)
#
tk.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to add a more loops in loop after points[] but it didn't work, so can you help please where it need to change to easily add auto scale or at least just enlarging ox and oy axes.

Comment: So  do you need to redraw canvas when you resize your application?

Comment: @AndrejKesely i,m need to resize already drawned lines, not canvas or app window. When you run code, you can move slider speed to left position and angel to center position, When you click DRAW IT, it drawing line, that far away from loop for() range and from graph. So need that code just automatically redraw already drawned lines, or at least automaticaly expand OX axe